# Uninstall OWIN and Identity packages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Several months ago I created an ASP.NET MVC project and I created it with the default authentification option: "Individual User Account", not on purpose.

My project runs well now but I don't need any authentification methods and so I don't need the Identity and OWIN packages.

Is there a clean way to delete all of those?
Those packages are not needed by any other features right?

Thx!

Comment: One idea is to read this article from the bottom to the top: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is simple just some uninstalling an removing some files.
First uninstall following package in package manage console:

```
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
PM> uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```

If everything goes right your project must clean up with following packeges:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Microsoft.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Microsoft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter
Owin
```

So if anyone still exist simply uninstall them also.

Now you could remove following files from your project:

```
App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs
App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs
Models\IdentityModels.cs
Startup.cs
```

Comment: Thx! I also removed some views.